# Postman returns a JSON result

Tags: .net, json, xml, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I wonder if this is a code related problem. 
In my WebApiConfig.cs, I set:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

In my chrome, and in firefox the result is in XML based format.

```
<ArrayOfMenuCategory>
    <MenuCategory Id="98" Name="Brunch"/>
    <MenuCategory Id="100" Name="Desserts"/>
    <MenuCategory Id="102" Name="Drinks"/>
    <MenuCategory Id="104" Name="Lunch"/>
    <MenuCategory Id="106" Name="Breakfast"/>
    <MenuCategory Id="108" Name="Dinner"/>
</ArrayOfMenuCategory>
```

In Postman, I indicated in Headers Content-Type = application/xml
But the result is posted below:

```
[
  {
    "Id": "98",
    "Name": "Brunch"
   },
  {
    "Id": "100",
    "Name": "Desserts"
  },
  {
    "Id": "102",
    "Name": "Drinks"
  },
  {
    "Id": "104",
    "Name": "Lunch"
  },
  {
    "Id": "106",
    "Name": "Breakfast"
  },
  {
    "Id": "108",
    "Name": "Dinner"
  }
]
```

Checking the postman:

Request-Headers: **Entity: Content-Type: application/xml**

Response-Headers: **Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8**

Any idea, why's postman doesn't return an xml result even I set the content-type ? JSOn is already the result in Edge browser.

Thanks.

Comment: I should've use the Accept Header instead of Content-Type. Figured out thru Postman

Answer (score 0):

Put this is `webapiconfig.cs`.

> config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes
>       .Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html") );